# Dúvida no livro Python on a Crash Course

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou estudando o livro *Python on a Crash Course* e estava indo tudo muito bem até agora. Depois de testar os códigos das páginas 324 e 325 (que são um módulo e um programinha que o usa), fui surpreendido com o fato de nada funcionar.

O que fazer para corrigir esse código e fazê-lo funcionar?

Aqui está o módulo `survey.py`:

```
class AnonymousSurvey():

    def __init__(self, question): #Aqui Esta em vermelho(problema)
        #Armazena uma pergunta e se prepara para armazenar asrespostas.
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def show_question(self):
        #Mostra a pergunta da pesquisa.
        print(question) #Aqui também esta (aparente problema)

    def store_response(self, new_response):
        #Armazena uma única resposta da pesquisa.
        self.responses.append(new_response)

    def show_results(self):
        #Mostra todas as respostas dadas.
        print("Survey results:")
        for response in responses:
            print('- ' + response)
```

E aqui está o programinha que usa o módulo acima:

```
from Modulo_Survey import AnonymousSurvey
# Define uma pergunta e cria uma pesquisa
question = 'What language did you first learn to speak?'
my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)


# Mostra a pergunta e armazena as respostas à pergunta
my_survey.show_question()
print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit.\n")
while True:
    response = input("Language: ")
    if response == 'q':
        break
my_survey.store_response(response)


# Exibe os resultados da pesquisa
print("\nThank you to everyone who participated in the survey!")
my_survey.show_results()
```

Comment: O que eu devo fazer pra isso ai funcionar??

Comment: Recomendo estudar um pouco mais sobre orientação a objeto, o que há de errado no seu código são apenas conceitos de orientação a objeto, como você disse que é um material de estudo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na quinta e sexta linha eles declaram `self.question` e `self.responses`. No entanto, na hora de referenciá-las mais adiante, nas linhas 10 e 19, eles usam `question` e `responses`. É só trocar elas por `self.question` e `self.responses`. Além disso, o `my_survey.store_response(response)` tem que ser indentado. Aqui vai o código corrigido:

Arquivo `survey.py`:

```
class AnonymousSurvey():

    def __init__(self, question):
        """Store a question, and prepare to store responses."""
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def show_question(self):
        """Show the survey question."""
        print(self.question)

    def store_response(self, new_response):
        """Store a single response to the survey."""
        self.responses.append(new_response)

    def show_results(self):
        """Show all the responses that have been given."""
        print("Survey results:")
        for response in self.responses:
            print('- ' + response)
```

Arquivo `language_survey.py`:

```
from survey import AnonymousSurvey

# Define a question, and make a survey.
question = "What language did you first learn to speak?"
my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)

# Show the question, and store responses to the question.
my_survey.show_question()
print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit.\n")
while True:
    response = input("Language: ")
    if response == 'q':
        break
    my_survey.store_response(response)

# Show the survey results.
print("\nThank you to everyone who participated in the survey!")
my_survey.show_results()
```

Comment: e o `my_survey.store_response(response)` certamente também seria para estar dentro do `while` mas suspeito que tenha sido descuido do AP ao tentar reproduzir o código

Comment: @Isac O meu livro não tem esse erro do `while`. Pode ter sido na formatação na hora de postar a pergunta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!!!!  :)   :0   
Meu Deus do céu , eu nunca ia encontrar esse erro. 
Obrigado.

Comment: @NamelessMan Esses erros são detalhes chave de programação orientada a objeto que eu recomendo você a dar uma revisada antes de continuar percorrendo esses exercícios do livro.

Comment: @NamelessMan Fica atento para o que o @Isac falou. Aquele `my_survey.store_response(response)` tem que estar indentado para dentro do código. Vou editar a resposta com tudo corrigido, ambos os arquivos.

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, eu li depois só. Ajeitei aqui, funcionou.

Comment: Corrigi de qualquer forma. Os comentários estão em inglês porque era minha versão do livro.

Comment: O livro em inglês Não esta com nenhum Erro ??

Comment: Está. Eu que corrigi.

Comment: Só para ficar aqui também, por vezes erros tem livros, acontece porque somos humanos. Muitos deles acabam até construindo uma Errata precisamente para que um futuro leitor possa perceber onde estão e rapidamente corrigir ou saber o que não está certo.